# Getting the label of "this" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

The following is my code for changing the color of the label of the input field in focus:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

var name = $(this).attr("name");

$(".comm-input").focus(function() {
    $("label[for=name]").css({"color" :"#669900"});
}); 

$(".comm-input").blur(function() {
    $("label[for=name]").css({"color" :"#999999"});
});     

});
```

.comm-input is the class of the input. Any ideas on why its not working?? Thanks!

Comment: I guess the code is not complete, because differently `var name = $(this).attr("name");` is getting an attribute of the global object (aka the object `window`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of issues.

Firstly, you're defining `name` in `ready()`. It won't have any (relevant) meaning there. The correct place to find that is inside your event handlers.

Secondly, you're not substituting the value of name, you're using the literal name. You want:

```
$(function() {
  $(".comm-input").focus(function() {
    $("label[for" + this.name + "]").css({"color" :"#669900"});
  }).blur(function() {
    $("label[for=" + this.name + "]").css({"color" :"#999999"});
  }); 
});
```

Lastly, I'd strongly suggest using a CSS class instead of directly setting CSS style attributes. They are problematic to remove. For example, what if the normal color is green? Your code will set it to something else it wasn't but removing a class will set it correctly so CSS:

```
label.highlight { color: #690; }
```

with:

```
$(function() {
  $(".comm-input").focus(function() {
    $("label[for" + this.name + "]").addClass("highlight");
  }).blur(function() {
    $("label[for=" + this.name + "]").removeClass("highlight");
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your selector to this:

```
$(".comm-input").focus(function() {
     $("label[for=" + this.name + "]")).css("color", "#669900");
});
```

It won't automatically change the string literal "name" with the value of your name variable.

Also, when you were grabbing the name variable, `this` refers to the document, not to the element being focused.